# Hybris promotion restriction

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, rule, promotions

I have two promotions. One of them is **bundle promotion** and other **coupon promotion**. I want a restriction that one of them is applied in cart.

I can with rule executed condition, but I don't know, it is a good solution.

How can achieve this?

Comment: which hybris version are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:
Put both of them in the same rule group and have them both be `stackable=false`.
This way only one of them should be executed (if both are fulfilled) based on the priority of the promotion.

**E.g.** if your **coupon promotion** has a higher priority and the customer applied the coupon, that one should be fired.
If the customer then removes the coupon code again, the other one should fire (if all other conditions are fulfilled).

Hope this helps!